# Magento E-Commerce - Add Out of Stock Watermark for items out of stock

Tags: php, magento

I'm using the Magento E-Commerce system.

Is there a way for me to set a "OUT OF STOCK" watermark on the product images when a product becomes out of stock?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to suggest an alternate solution. Instead of generating and displaying a new image with the watermark, perhaps you can add an element above the image (css z-index) that says "Out of Stock" when the product is out of stock. Check out how we did this for products on sale (this link has a product on sale as of the time of this post: http://www.abesmarket.com/store/karmaorganicspa). The code that @Showket wrote `$_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()` is good for determining if a product is in stock. If the product is not in stock, I would display a new div which is positioned on top of the product image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Ofcourse You can Do that..If you want to do it with code you can do like This :-

Go to `/app/design/frontend/your_theame/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and do the following changes at or near Line 96, You ll find some lines from this code and i have added few in it, just apply the changes and u ll get it done. revert back in case of any errors

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
<?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul class="products-grid">
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($_product->getStock_item()->getIs_in_stock()){
            $inStock = "In Stock Now";}
            else{
            $inStock = "Out Of Stock";
            }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is little code snippets from

```
Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
/**
 * Add watermark to image
 * size param in format 100x200
 *
 * @param string $fileName
 * @param string $position
 * @param string $size
 * @param int $imageOpacity
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image
 */
public function watermark($fileName, $position, $size=null, $imageOpacity=null)
{
    $this->setWatermark($fileName)
        ->setWatermarkPosition($position)
        ->setWatermarkSize($size)
        ->setWatermarkImageOpacity($imageOpacity);
    return $this;
}
```

Also you might be insterested in:

```
Mage_Catalog_ProductController
imageAction()
...
    try {
        $imageModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_image');
        $imageModel->setSize($size)
            ->setBaseFile($imageFile)
            /**
             * Resizing has been commented because this one method are deprecated
             */
            //->resize()
            ->setWatermark( Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/watermark/image') )
            ->saveFile()
            ->push();
    } catch( Exception $e ) {
        $this->_forward('noRoute');
    }
...
```

These are two functions which you might be interested in.

catalog/product/list.phtml has following line of code:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

So to init image with watermarik we can you something like this:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135)->watermark('yourfile');
```

I don't know how good you are with programming, but I guess you should be able to put some if-else conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, you need to customize the Magento code.

Check the stock available of the product and change image or put watermark according to that.

Comment: Dear Sankar, Yes I know will need to customize the code. Any idea where I can look? I manage hundreds of products, its crazy to change when an item goes out of stock.  Any help appreciated. Thanks.